# link href only works in chrome

Tags: html, button, hyperlink

Im making a button that opens a link (web site), but the problem is that it only works on chrome!!  why??
[link here!](http://www.alouette.com.au/indexo.htm)

here the simple html code>

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
<title>HTML and CSS Rounded Corner Button Generated By iWebToolsOnline.com</title>
<link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style href>a {text-decoration: none} </style>
 </head>
  <body>
<h3>&nbsp;</h3>
<button class="rounded">
  <a href="http://www.iwebtoolsonline.com/rss-feed-icon-generator">
  <span>Save</span>
  </a>
</button>
 <br/><br/>

 </body>
  </html>
```

CSS

```
button {
 border: 0 none;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 0 15px 0 0;
 text-align: center;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 width: auto;
 }

 button.rounded {
 background: transparent url( btn_right.png ) no-repeat scroll right top;
 clear: left;
 font-family: "Kristen ITC";
 font-size: 36px;

  }

  button span {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
   }

  button.rounded span {
  background: transparent url( btn_left.png ) no-repeat scroll left top;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  }

  button.rounded:hover {
  background-position: 100% -40px;
  }

  button.rounded:hover span {
  background-position: 0% -40px;
  }

  button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
  }
```

You can find the link from the generator I used for the button in the link Im trying to go to, the generator doesn't give the code for the link so I just used href in the button, I this not done properly??
what else could be the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps try putting the A tag outside the BUTTON tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
  <a href="http://www.iwebtoolsonline.com/rss-feed-icon-generator">
  <button class="rounded">Save</button>
  </a>
```

But this wont work in IE6 or 7 (you will need to emulate it with JS (JQuery example)) :

```
$("a button").click(function() {
   window.location.href = $(this).parent().attr("href");
});
```

But still in Firefox it will call twice that page (maybe it won't matter you). There is bug report about that (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=577035).

Just remember that having "BUTTON" inside "A" is against W3C standard recommendations.